# How to hide an option from dropdown in filter module

Tags: plugins, php, search

I'm using LearnPress LMS plugin and it doesn't offer an option to hide filter taxonomies. I want to hide the "most members" from dropdown filter. I've tried searching the term in plugin files through editor but all in vain.

[image: ss]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I applied this custom js to hide that specific taxonomy in the dropdown.

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
var arr=['name-of-slug-to-hide'];
$('select[name="wpv-category"] option').each(function(){
if(jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), arr)>=0){
$(this).hide();
}
});
})
</script>
```